# Regular expression to match letter inside brackets

Tags: ruby, regex

I need to write a regular expression that matches all strings containing one or more of the following substrings (including the curly brackets):

```
{NN}
{NNN}
{NNNN}
{NNNNN}
{NNNNNN}
```

I am completely new to regular expressions. Can anybody help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Learning Regular Expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736/learning-regular-expressions)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
r = /
    \{      # match left brace
    N{2,6}  # match between 2 and 6 Ns
    \}      # match right brace
    /x      # free-spacing regex definition mode

arr = %w|{N} {NN} {NNN} {NNNN} {NNNNN} {NNNNNN} {NNNNNNN} {NNMN}|
  #=> ["{N}", "{NN}", "{NNN}", "{NNNN}", "cat{NNNNN}dog", "{NNNNNN}",
  #    "{NNNNNNN}", "{NNMN}"]

arr.each { |s| puts "'#{s}'.match(r) = #{s.match?(r)}" }
'{N}'.match(r) = false
'{NN}'.match(r) = true
'{NNN}'.match(r) = true
'{NNNN}'.match(r) = true
'cat{NNNNN}dog'.match(r) = true
'{NNNNNN}'.match(r) = true
'{NNNNNNN}'.match(r) = false
'{NNMN}'.match(r) = false
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify language / interface you'd be using... In general: `\{.*?\}` . Replace `.*?` with `N{2,6}?` if you want to match only the string you presented.

Ruby example:

```
if ( content =~ /\{N{2,6}\}/ )
   puts "Content match!"
end
```

Comment: I am using Ruby on Rails.